# With GIMP 2.10, how can I automatically sort and organize layers most efficiently on a canvas?

Tags: gimp, print-design, print-production, script, photomontage

In order to print a lot of photos at scale, I create a huge canvas in GIMP and drag the images, then organize by hand. The result looks like this.

[image: Amalgam of photos to print]

I feel like GIMP could do its own organization of the layers by size better than I can by hand but maybe not. It could even rotate the images 90' if it were more efficient in space which I don't even consider when organizing myself.

I'm afraid an approach with a horizontally-uniform grid will not be as efficient as a dynamic sort-by-size in terms of the amount of paper used.

Is by hand the best way to get such a job done or can GIMP be scripted to do a similar job? I also looked into montage -mode Concatenate but the results were not what i was looking for.

Comment: These are my wedding photos, I gave myself permission to post them.

Comment: No images should be resized!

Comment: Did the other people give you the permission to publish the photos where they appear?

Comment: Gimp can be scripted it you have an algorithm... but then this is a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: You'd need a script for that in GIMP.  However it can be done in Inkscape (also free and Open Source) using the Align and Distribute Grid function. [see example](https://imgur.com/5rwI3tR)